# How do I know what light bulb size I should get for a socket? The socket is smaller than the average socket

Tags: light-fixture, bulb, socket

There is a light bulb socket which is much smaller than a regular light bulb socket, so I think I need some sort of specialty light bulb.

How do I know what size to get?

Comment: Does it use screw threads or some other setup? Can you give us photos of the socket, or a measurement of its inside diameter for that matter?

Comment: What country? Is it a screw bulb? A *candelabra* is a common small screw bulb in the US.

Comment: Take the old bulb to the store with you so you can find one to match.

Comment: Welcome to diy.se.  If you can, [edit] your question to include a photograph of the socket with a ruler/yardstick/measuring tape right on top of it.  If you don’t have that, stick a USB A-type plug alongside it.

Comment: If you have a bulb that came out, a photo of that bulb's fitting would also be useful. Or take that bulb to a shop and find a helpful assistant to identify it. Any way around, someone has to have an idea what it looks like to be able to identify it.

Answer (score 2):

The two most common screw type bulbs in the US are the standard Edison 1" base now normally described by it's international metric standardization as an E26 and the 1/2" E12 candelabra base.

There is also an "Intermediate" socket, an E17 that is mostly used in appliances, and an E11 minicandelabra that is almost always a halogen lamp.

A picture would help.